# "Share" dialog disappears in review queues

Tags: bug, review, share-this

Earlier today I was reviewing some questions and answers on Ask Ubuntu. I was finding a lot of NAAs (not an answer), so I was sharing them in AU chat for others to flag.

Since I needed to share a link, I chose to click the `Share` button and copy the link the modal dialog gave me. It worked once or twice, but after that, clicking `Share` would bring up the dialog, but it would disappear right away, before I could copy the link.

Going into another queue fixed it (I believe) temporarily (as in, let me copy once or twice more), and so did completely exiting the review area and coming back later.

I thought it was because of my website color inverter (night mode) extension, but I asked another user to try, and he had the same problem.

This is the process which he used to reproduce:

- Enter a queue and hit the `Share` button
- Switch back and go to the next item in the queue
- Click `Share` again
- Repeat the previous two steps until it happens.

Both I and the other user are using Google Chrome. I'm on Windows 10, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 and he's on Ubuntu, Chrome 54.0.2837.0. I have also tested in Firefox 48 (I can't tell the exact version because I can't figure out how to see that on FF) and it does the same thing. This is a completely fresh install (I installed it specifically to test).

I'm not sure if this has been brought up before (I didn't see it on the first page), so I apologize if it has. I also don't know if this is AU-specific, as it's the only SE site where I can review.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'll edit it in. @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN

Comment: Can confirm in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 48.0

Comment: Reproducible in SO. There is also no need to switch tabs to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Not a fix, but you don't need the modal window to get the permalink to a question or answer. Right-click "share" and "copy link" (or whatever your browser's equivalent is).

Comment: @AlE. Yeah. I just (usually accidentally while trying to speed-copy) hit ctrl and then click the link, which opens it in a background tab.

Comment: It seems to be happening on all sites, on all browsers, from the *second* item you review (it works for the first item).